# make a request to take server sent events in nodejs

Tags: node.js, client-side, server-sent-events

I have a api that sends "server sent events" in real time. I need receive this data and process it in nodejs but all of information I´ve find refers to do capture events from a client side in a javascript code.

I don´t know if there are nodejs modules to do what I want in node.js

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can receive server-sent events in node.js with the [eventsource](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventsource) module.
It is a pure JavaScript implementation of the [EventSource](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#server-sent-events) client.